lack of the drop-down menu after click on the button
I can't unwrap menu in mobile version of my site. I don't know what is wrong in my code.
I added the code for the JavaScript file and I wanted to unwrap menu, when a user click on the menu button. It seemed to me that I styled it proper for my CSS file.


const navbar = document.querySelector("nav");
const openMenu = document.getElementById("menu-button");
const closeMenu = document.getElementById("menu-close");

openMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navbar.classList.add("open");
})

closeMenu.addEventListener("click", function() {
  navbar.classList.remove("open");
})
.attribution {
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}

.attribution a {
  color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%);
}

.body {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Inter", sans-serif;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

#menu-close {
  display: none;
  border: none;
  background: none;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-left: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%
}

nav {
  margin-left: auto;
}

a {
  margin-right: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(73, 72, 72)
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 60px;
}

.news {
  background-color: hsl(240, 100%, 5%);
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 2;
  padding: 15px
}

.news h2 {
  color: hsl(36, 100%, 99%);
}

.news p {
  color: hsl(36, 100%, 99%);
  text-align: justify
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background: hsl(5, 85%, 63%);
  border: 0.75px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 14px;
  width: 50%
}

a h2:hover {
  color: hsl(35, 77%, 62%)
}

li a:hover {
  color: hsl(5, 85%, 63%)
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer
}

.main-image-desktop {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto
}

.additional {
  display: flex;
  grid-row: 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  flex: 1;
  gap: 20px;
  margin: 0
}

.news h1 {
  color: hsl(35, 77%, 62%);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.extra-article {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px
}

#main-title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3rem
}

.number {
  color: hsl(5, 85%, 63%);
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.extra-article span {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}

.extra-article span:hover {
  color: hsl(5, 85%, 63%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.description {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.main-article {
  display: flex;
  gap: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.description-text {
  line-height: 150%
}

.news {
  margin-bottom: 20px
}

#toggle-navigation {
  display: none
}

.main-image-mobile {
  display: none
}

#menu-button {
  display: none
}

li {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

@media(max-width: 375px) {
  ul {
    display: none;
  }
  nav {
    width: 100%
  }
  nav.open {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding-inline: 0px;
  }
  .additional {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .main-article {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .attribution {
    text-align: center;
  }
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
  .main-image-mobile {
    display: block;
  }
  .main-image-desktop {
    display: none;
  }
  header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .menu-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  nav.open ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  #menu-button {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: white;
    border: none
  }
  nav.open #menu-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  nav.open #menu-button {
    display: none
  }
}

header img {
  max-width: 100%
}
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:ital,opsz,wght@0,14..32,100..900;1,14..32,100..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">


<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="./assets/images/logo.svg" />
  </div>
  <nav>
    <button id="menu-close">
        <img src="assets/images/icon-menu-close.svg" alt="cross close menu">
      </button>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>New</li>
      <li>Popular</li>
      <li>Trending</li>
      <li>Categories</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="menu-button">
    <button id="menu-button">
        <img src="assets/images/icon-menu.svg" alt="icon-menu">
      </button>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="main-image-desktop" src="./assets/images/image-web-3-desktop.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="main-image-mobile" src="./assets/images/image-web-3-mobile.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="main-article">
      <p id="main-title">The Bright Future of Web 3.0?</p>

      <div class="description">
        <div class="description-text">
          <p>We dive into the next evolution of the web that claims to put the power of the platforms back into the hands of the people. But is it really fulfilling its promise?</p>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Read more"></a>
      </div>
      </description>
    </div>

    <div class="news">
      <h1>New</h1>

      <div class="information">
        <a href='#'>
          <h2>Hydrogen VS Electric Cars</h2>
        </a>
        <p>Will hydrogen-fueled cars ever catch up to EVs?</p>
        <hr />
      </div>

      <div class="information">
        <a href='#'>
          <h2>The Downsides of AI Artistry</h2>
        </a>
        <p>What are the possible adverse effects of on-demand AI image generation?</p>
        <hr />
      </div>

      <div class="information">
        <a href="#">
          <h2>Is VC Funding Drying Up?</h2>
        </a>
        <p>Private funding by VC firms is down 50% YOY. We take a look at what that means.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="additional">
      <div class="extra-article">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="./assets/images/image-retro-pcs.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-description">
          <p class="number">01</p>
          <span>Reviving Retro PCs</span>
          <p>What happens when old PCs are given modern upgrades?</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="extra-article">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="./assets/images/image-top-laptops.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-description">
          <p class="number">02</p>
          <span>Top 10 Laptops of 2022</span>
          <p>Our best picks for various needs and budgets.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="extra-article">
        <div class="image">
          <img src="./assets/images/image-gaming-growth.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="image-description">
          <p class="number">03</p>
          <span>The Growth of Gaming</span>
          <p>How the pandemic has sparked fresh opportunities.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  <div class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. Coded by <a href="https://github.com/NatKacz99">NatKacz99</a>.
  </div>
</footer>




I added the JS file into the wrong folder, therefore I couldn't unwrap this menu. So the problem is just solved

openMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  navbar.classList.add("open");
  openMenu.style.display = "none";
  closeMenu.style.display = "inline-block";
})

closeMenu.addEventListener("click", function () {
  navbar.classList.remove("open");
  openMenu.style.display = "inline-block";
  closeMenu.style.display = "none";
})


You need to add some comments/explanation on how you came to the conclusion that the answer provided answers the OP's question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer
